# What should the class name of the element be to work?

Tags: css, next.js

This is a part of my Next.js code below:

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import gfm from 'remark-gfm'
import styles from './content.module.css'
```

```js
return (
  <article className={styles.markdownbody}>  // here
    <ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[gfm]}>
    {props.markdown}
    </ReactMarkdown>
  </article>
)
```

This is a part of my CSS style below:

```css
.markdown-body {
  color-scheme: dark;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #e6edf3;
  background-color: #0d1117;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Noto Sans",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji";
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

So what should `className` be to work?

I tried `styles.markdownbody`, `styles.markdown_body`, `styles.markdownBody`, `styles.markdown-body` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names in CSS modules are not processed, so you'd have to explicitly do:

```js
styles['markdown-body']
```

(logging the `styles` variable would reveal that)

[From the docs](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules):

> ### Naming
>
> For local class names camelCase naming is recommended, but not enforced.
>
> This is recommended because the common alternative, kebab-casing may cause unexpected behavior when trying to access style.class-name as a dot notation. You can still work around kebab-case with bracket notation (eg. `style['class-name']`) but `style.className` is cleaner.